# Out of memory error when projecting a bipartite network in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a directed, bipartite graph `g` with 215473 vertices and 2326714 edges. When creating a `bipartite.projection` of `g`, I keep running out of memory (it uses ~35 gig of RAM before crashing).

I tried to calculate how much memory I need, by following a [previous thread on nongnu.org](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2009-03/msg00108.html).

From the information provided in this thread, to store a graph in memory costs (in bytes):

```
(4*|E|+2*|V|) * 8 + 4*|V|
```

To calculate the projection requires the following memory (in bytes):

```
16*|V| + (2*|V|+2*|E|) * 8
```

Thus, for my graph `g`, it would cost:

```
((4*2326714+2*215473) * 8 + 4*215473) + (16*215473 + (2*215473+2*2326714) * 8)

= 78764308 + 44122560
= 122886868 (bytes)
= 122.886868 (mb)
```

Clearly, this isn't correct, and I must be doing something wrong.

**Can anyone please help figure out how to create a bipartite projection of my graph?**

Answer (score 3):

Working with sparse matrices could possibly solve your problem.

```
# Load tiny toy data as edgelist
df <- data.frame( person =
    c('Sam','Sam','Sam','Greg','Tom','Tom','Tom','Mary','Mary'), group =
    c('a','b','c','a','b','c','d','b','d'), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Transform data to a sparse matrix
library(Matrix)
A <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(nrow=length(unique(df$person)),
        ncol=length(unique(df$group)),
        i = as.numeric(factor(df$person)),
        j = as.numeric(factor(df$group)),
        x = rep(1, length(as.numeric(df$person))) )
row.names(A) <- levels(factor(df$person))
colnames(A) <- levels(factor(df$group))
```

To do the projection you have acutally multiple possiblities, here are two:

```
# Use base r
Arow <- tcrossprod(A)
# Alternatively, if you want to project on the other mode:
Acol <- tcrossprod(t(A))

# Use the igraph package, which works with sparse matrices
library(igraph)
g <- graph.incidence(A)

# The command bipartite.projection does both possible projections at once
proj <- bipartite.projection(g)

#proj[[1]]
#proj[[2]]
```

You can also read-in the data and do the transformation within the `spMatrix` command by using `data.table`, which will speed up those operations as well.

**UPDATE**:

Here is an example with a larger graph and some memory benchmarks:

```
# Load packages
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

# Scientific collaboration dataset
# Descriptives as reported on https://toreopsahl.com/datasets/#newman2001 
# mode 1 elements: 16726    
# mode 2 elements: 22016    
# two mode ties: 58595
# one mode ties: 47594  
d <- fread("http://opsahl.co.uk/tnet/datasets/Newman-Cond_mat_95-99-two_mode.txt", 
           stringsAsFactors=TRUE, colClasses = "factor", header=FALSE)

# Transform data to a sparse matrix
A <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(nrow=length(unique(d[, V1])),
              ncol=length(unique(d[, V2])),
              i = as.numeric(d[, V1]),
              j = as.numeric(d[, V2]),
              x = rep(1, length(as.numeric(d[, V1]))) )
row.names(A) <- levels(d[, V1])
colnames(A) <- levels(d[, V2])

#To do the projection you have acutally multiple possiblities, here are two:
  
# Use base r
Arow <- tcrossprod(A)
# Alternatively, if you want to project on the other mode:
Acol <- tcrossprod(t(A))
```

Here is a overview how much memory got used, i.e. the sparse matrix approach worked on my laptop for this network, but the approach using regular matrices did give a memory allocation error (even after removing the `Bcol` object from memory with `rm(Brow)` and then calling the garbage collector `gc()`)

```
object.size(A) # Spare matrix: 3108520 bytes
object.size(Arow) # 2713768 bytes
object.size(Acol) # 5542104 bytes

# For comparison
object.size(B <- as.matrix(A)) # Regular matrix: 2945783320 bytes
object.size(Brow <- tcrossprod(B)) # 2239946368 bytes
object.size(Bcol <- tcrossprod(t(B))) # Memory allocation error on my laptop
```

Comment: Hi @majom, I tried using the `mode` parameter of `graph.incidence` but this does not control the type of projection. As per help file, `mode` "defines the direction of the edges in directed graphs".

Using `tcrossprod` provides a sparse matrix that I can use to create one-mode graphs, but when I try to do so I run into the exact same problem with out of memory errors.

Comment: My fault, I just added the command `bipartite.projection` which does the projections in `igraph`. A short-term solution (albeit not a super nice one) to your out-of-memory problem is to go to EC2 and get a large memory instance and do your analysis through RStudio server: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/video_guide.html

Comment: @timothyjgraham: I added an example which shows how sparse matrices help to solve the exact problem you have. The network size in this example is s"ignificant", albeit not as large as yours. Please check that you do clean your memory using `rm()`and  `gc()` when trying out different approaches. You can also just restart you R session when trying a new approach.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. The major problem occurs when trying running the `bipartite.projection` function on the sparse matrix. Unfortunately it appears the only solution is to follow your suggestion to use EC2. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Another option would be to try to change your BLAS, see here for the effect on `tcrossprod()`: http://simplystatistics.org/2016/01/21/parallel-blas-in-r/ . Perhaps they did not only optimize speed, but also memory usage. For Windows you would just install Microsoft R Open and for Mac follow this instruction: http://r.research.att.com/man/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Which-BLAS-is-used-and-how-can-it-be-changed_003f

Comment: Almost 7 years later, this solution is still great for working with very large graphs. The matrix multiplication works much better than igraphs implementation for projecting bipartite graphs.

Just note that today `Matrix::spMatrix` is deprecated and `Matrix::sparseMatrix` should be used instead.